# Powershell: Change values in CSV file based on certain criteria

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with data like this..

Data.csv

```
Name, Machine, Model, Wifi
User1, Machine1, Dell Lattitude, Connected
User2, Machine2, Dell Lattitude, disconnected
User3, Machine3, Dell Lattitude, Connected
```

I also have txt file with specific machines like this

desktops.txt

```
machine1
machine4
machine5
```

What i need to do is change the "WIFI" value from "connected' to "connected*" if the machine has a value of "connected" and its also in the desktops.txt file

Here is the code i have, but its not changing the WIFI value on any rows.

```
$ImportedCSV = Import-CSV data.csv

foreach($server in Get-Content .\desktops.txt) {
    $NewCSV = Foreach ($Entry in $ImportedCsv) {
        $SEL = Select-String -Path desktops.txt -Pattern "$server"
        if (($SEL -eq $True) -and ($Entry.WIFI -eq 'connected')) {
            $Entry.WIFI = 'connected*'
        }
        $Entry
    }
}

$NewCSV | Export-CSV data2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Desired CSV output is

```
Name, Machine, Model, Wifi
User1, Machine1, Dell Lattitude, Connected*
User2, Machine2, Dell Lattitude, disconnected
User3, Machine3, Dell Lattitude, Connected
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Select-String` on data you have imported with `Import-Csv`. Instead, just probe the properties on each item:

```
# read the machines as string array
$machines = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\desktops.txt'
# loop through the data and replace the Wifi property when needed
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\data.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($machines -contains $_.Machine -and $_.Wifi -eq 'Connected') {
        $_.Wifi = 'Connected*'
    }
    # now output the row changed or unchanged to build the $csv
    $_
}

# output on screen
$csv | Format-Table -AutoSize   # or $csv | Out-GridView 

# output to (new) csv file
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\newdata.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output on screen using `Format-Table`:

```
Name  Machine  Model          Wifi        
----  -------  -----          ----        
User1 Machine1 Dell Lattitude Connected*  
User2 Machine2 Dell Lattitude disconnected
User3 Machine3 Dell Lattitude Connected
```